# How does the different layouts in awesome work?

Tags: awesome-wm

I have been using [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) in on ubuntu 14.04 for a while. The default layouts defined in `rc.lua` is:

```
layouts =
{
    awful.layout.suit.floating,
    awful.layout.suit.tile,
    awful.layout.suit.tile.left,
    awful.layout.suit.tile.bottom,
    awful.layout.suit.tile.top,
    awful.layout.suit.fair,
    awful.layout.suit.fair.horizontal,
    awful.layout.suit.spiral,
    awful.layout.suit.spiral.dwindle,
    awful.layout.suit.max,
    awful.layout.suit.max.fullscreen,
    awful.layout.suit.magnifier
}
```

I have a hard time to wrap my head around this! Some of them I managed to understand (I think) just by testing them out, but not all of them.

I have tried to find some documentation that describes it but with no success. Is there some documentation where I can read about them and the conceptual thoughts behind it all? When and how they are suitable for different tasks.

I understand that its individual but if there was some sort of information at all about these things the awesome community would benefit greatly form that I think!

Answer (score 5):

I understand a visual documentation would be *awesome*, but afaik there is none. There is a (very superficial) text description [here](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/libraries/awful.layout.html#Client_layouts), though, which I'm transcribing (which some minor fixes) below:

- awful.layout.suit.corner.nw

Corner layout. Display master client in a corner of the screen, and slaves in one column and one row around the master.

- awful.layout.suit.corner.ne

Corner layout. Display master client in a corner of the screen, and slaves in one column and one row around the master.

- awful.layout.suit.corner.sw

Corner layout. Display master client in a corner of the screen, and slaves in one column and one row around the master.

- awful.layout.suit.corner.se

Corner layout. Display master client in a corner of the screen, and slaves in one column and one row around the master.

- awful.layout.suit.floating

The floating layout.

- awful.layout.suit.magnifier

The magnifier layout.

- awful.layout.suit.max

Maximized layout.

- awful.layout.suit.max.fullscreen

Fullscreen layout.

- awful.layout.suit.spiral.dwindle

Dwindle layout.

- awful.layout.suit.spiral

Spiral layout.

- awful.layout.suit.tile.right

The main tile algo, on the right.

- awful.layout.suit.tile.left

The main tile algo, on the left.

- awful.layout.suit.tile.bottom

The main tile algo, on the bottom.

- awful.layout.suit.tile.top

The main tile algo, on the top.

Answer (score -3):

The documentation [layouts](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Layout) details them.

Some issues can occur to understand what happened when you use these layouts when you "accidentally" press `ModKey + Shift + h` or `ModKey + Ctrl + h`. It modifies the tile view.

Try the layout with these modification to find the best layout for your needs.